# Node update date changes when saving without changing anything

Tags: 6, users

Why does the timestamp of node_revisions and changed of node tables are updated when I save a node without making any changes?

All I want to know if anything ever changed in a node (revision). Is there a way to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save a node then it *has* changed according to Drupal...regardless of whether or not any specific property/CCK field values have actually been changed.

You can find the evidence for this in the [`node_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/6) function which contains this line of code which runs for every single call to the function:

```
// The changed timestamp is always updated for bookkeeping purposes (revisions, searching, ...)
$node->changed = $time;
```

Drupal does not do any sort of `diff` against the current and new revisions of a node when saving, so if you've pressed "Save" it makes the assumption that you wanted to add a new revision of the node.

Comment: I want to use Revisions module to direct a new node change to a moderator. Unfortunately there does not seem to be any way to forward only those nodes whose data have changed

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [Diff](http://drupal.org/project/diff) module could be helpful for you. It shows the changes between revisions.

> This module adds a tab for sufficiently permissioned users. The tab shows all revisions like standard Drupal but it also allows pretty viewing of all added/changed/deleted words between revisions.

Comment: What does it show if node is saved as a new revision without any changes?